# MATE Menu Has No Applications Debian

Tags: debian, mate-desktop

My MATE Menu has nothing in it but places, In Mozo it says it has all the applications and categories but nothing is there. Can anyone help? also Mozo can't be run without sudo.
I Have Debian Jessie + MATE

Answer (score 0):

Try to right-click to the menu -> `preferences` ->  `plugins` and the select application and system plugins.